# How can i use websocket to keep me updated with the live data which is in 3rd party api

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, websocket

The question is there are lots of tutorials about the websocket on chat server, but chat server received message and broadcast to all open connection using websocket, but here my scenario is i have an Stock API

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo
```

which i want to keep updating in my application live, Ex. If the API data changes it need to be reflected in my application.

How can i do it. For websocket it uses ws:// connection but the api which i'm using doesn't have websocket connection

I'm Using Angular 5 as front end & Node for database operations.

Answer (score 1):

So from what it seems the API that you posted is a GET REST API and you have to do a polling with interval of `1` minute or `60000` milliseconds to receive updates.

If you try to get the information more often you will get an error `{
    "Error Message": "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY."
}`

You can use `setInterval` or other `RxJS` methods for the polling.

If you want to have web socket connection, you have to find a 3rd party that has a WS API, integrate it with your backend (NodeJS) and then establish a WS connection with your front-end (Angular).